# Is having a file uploading form on my site a security risk?

Tags: security, file-upload

I have a form with file uploads, what do I need to do to make sure it doesn't pose any security problems?
here is how i am adding it

```
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'certificate', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'Certificate',
    'input'     => 'file',
    'position'  => 1290,
    'required'  => true,
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'certificate');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();
```

and i put it in the phtml with this

```
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" class="scaffold-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="field">
    <label for="ts_certificate"><?php echo $this->__('Certificate') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="file" name="ts_certificate" title="<?php echo $this->__('Certificate') ?>" id="ts_certificate" class="input-text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should post your controller part for the post action. The problem may come from there.

Comment: `index.php/customer/account/createpost/`

Comment: it is the stranded register a new customer page i added a field to allow image uploads

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you are using the default POST action for customer registration, so you are quite ok.

Just add `form_key` by adding inside your form if you are creating a custom one.

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

P.S: Make sure your uploaded documents is not accessible from outside public traffic if you want to keep them secret.

If it is an image I suggest you to use:

```
'type'    => 'varchar',
'input'   => 'image',
'backend' => 'some/backend_model'
```

To define a backend model have a look here to understand how to make it: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Attribute_Backend_Image`

Comment: the POST action is protected?

Comment: What do you mean by "protected" ?

Comment: That no one can use the form to inject server side scripts or any of the other vulnerabilities that come along with allowing users to upload forms to the site

Comment: This is why I suggested to make sure the file is not readable from public. The other possibility is to override the post action and very the file. Or he could use an image field.

Comment: making sure the file is not readable from public only helps to prevent someone from executing the script within the file, I think he also needs to make sure no one can hack the post method with the included upload file

Comment: The formkey protects him from CSRF and parameters escaping is handled by Magento. Unless he run an "include" inside his POST method I cannot see how it could happen. And he is using the default customer POST action.

Comment: Anyway I modified my comment adding a backend model to check and manipualte the image if needed.